# Out of nothing comes something (Ex quidem nihil fit?)

Tags: translation-check, english-to-latin-translation

If "*ex nihilo nihil fit*" means "out of nothing comes nothing" then how would one say "out of nothing comes something"? The best I can come up with is "*ex quidem nihil fit*." Is that translation correct?

Answer (score 9):

I think quidem is wrong here, as it is an adverb. You can confirm this on the [Lewis and Short dictionary](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dquidem). Also, you need to keep the ablative phrase "ex nihilo" (you changed it to "ex quidem").

I would use this phrase: **aliquid ex nihilo fit**. I'm using the word "aliquid" to mean "something", but there might be better choices.

Comment: If it's a separate phrase without more context, can you really use *quid* for "something"?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Hm, I don't know. Do you think aliquid would be better? Or does it run into the same problem?

Comment: *Aliquid* is good here. The *quid* sounds wrong to me, but I may be mistaken.

Comment: I think you are right. I looked it up somewhere, and it says that the indefinite pronoun "quid" is used after certain words, like si, nisi, ne, and num. I'm assuming that in other contexts it should be "aliquid".

Comment: That's exactly what I had in mind!

Answer (score 8):

With Pliny's well-known *ex Africa semper aliquid novi* in mind, is there any real need for a verb here?

I would use *ex nihilo aliquid*.

Comment: +1, but [apparently](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Talk:Latin_proverbs#Ex_Africa_semper_aliquid_novi) Pliny actually didn't say *ex Africa semper aliquid novi*, he said "Semper aliquid novi Africam adferre".

Comment: Thanks for the +1 and your reminder that it's not original to Pliny. It's an ancient aphorism, still commonly used, and so a useful pattern here.

Comment: If I wanted to say it as a question, would it be grammatical to ask, "Ex nihilo aliquid?" That is, 'something from nothing?'

Answer (score 5):

I would use the word *nonnihil*, "not nothing" or "something".
It also makes the comparison to the original phrase clear.

> *Ex nihilo nonnihil fit.*